# Apache handling multiple domains with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I want apache to run django mod_wsgi and php application on one server. I have made changes in conf.d file below but its not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.temp.in
   #Django Application
   <Directory /django>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web.temp.in
    ServerAlias web.temp.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently both the domains are redirecting to api.temp.in(django/mod_wsgi) .Is it even possible with mod_wsgi ?

Comment: Which version of apache you using? 2.2 or 2.4 ? run httpd -v to find out the version.

Comment: **Apache/2.4.6**

Answer (score 0):

Check you have a working virtual host entry.

**Try this**

```
<virtualhost   *:80>
    servername  api.temp.in
        documentroot  /var/www/html/api.temp.in
</virtualhost>


<virtualhost   *:80>
    servername  web.temp.in
        documentroot  /var/www/html/web.temp.in
</virtualhost>


mkdir   /var/www/html/api.temp.in   /var/www/html/web.temp.in

echo “<h1> api.temp.in </h1>” >  /var/www/html/api.temp.in/index.html
echo “<h1> web.temp.in </h1>” >  /var/www/html/web.temp.in/index.html
```

**Then try to access it , don’t forget to add /etc/hosts entry.**

Comment: This works when hosting multiple domains using only apache server, but here I am  running one domain with **mod_wsgi** , hence redirecting apache to wsgi .